# change existant CSS class proprety with jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, css

i'm new with **jQuery** ! 
i have a **CSS** file named **"Slider.css"** that contains the following code :

```
.banner1 {
    /*background: url(../images/bnr1.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;*/
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 650px;
}

.banner2 {
   /* background: url(../images/bnr2.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;*/
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 650px;
}

.banner3 {
   /* background: url(../images/bnr3.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;*/
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 650px;
}
```

what i want is to change the url of the background in page called **home.ctp** according to data that i get from database so i tried this :

```
  <?php $i=1; ?>
     <?php foreach ($query as $slider): ?> // query contain 3 items
         <div  class="slid banner<?= $i; ?>">
               <div class="caption">
                       <h3><?= $slider->titre; ?></h3>
                        <p><?= $slider->contenue; ?></p>
                        <a href="#" class="button">know more</a>
                  </div>
            </div>
                <script>
                   // alert(".banner<?= $i; ?>");
                    $(".banner<?= $i; ?>").css({"background": "url(../images/<?= $slider->url ?>) no-repeat 0px 0px;"})
                </script>
                <?php $i++; ?>;
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So i tried  `$(".banner<?= $i; ?>").css({"background": "url(../images/<?= $slider->url ?>) no-repeat 0px 0px;"})` but it doesn't change anythnig..

How can i change the css of `Slider.css` from php Loop using jQuery !
Thanks for help

Comment: Just a generic advise: please do not mix server side code (php) with client side (html/js), if not for trivial code...

Comment: And, you don't expect slider.css **file** to be changed, right? `$(element).css(property, value)` only changes DOM...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you're doing it wrong.  You don't need and shouldn't be using jQuery for this.

This is what you want:

```css
.banner {
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 650px;
}
```

```html
<?php foreach ($query as $slider): ?>// query contain 3 items
<div class="slid banner" style="background: url(../images/<?= $slider->url ?>) no-repeat 0px 0px;">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3><?= $slider->titre; ?></h3>
    <p>
      <?=$ slider->contenue; ?></p>
    <a href="#" class="button">know more</a>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thnk you a lot for your answer ! i removed all the classes ( banner1/2/3) from `slider.css` and added them in style option of the div and it works now !

Answer (score 3):

You don't need jQuery to achieve this. If `$slider->url` contains the URL of your background image, just do:

```
<?php $i = 1; foreach ($query as $slider): ?>
  <div class="slid banner<?php echo $i; ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $slider->url; ?>)">
    // ...
  </div>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

Indeed, your CSS already defines the background image, you shouldn't even need this. Just the `<div class="slid banner<?echo $i; ?>">` does the trick.

Comment: By the way, if you need an index inside your loop, consider using `for` instead of `foreach`.